# how to access child of parent node without affecting other child in that same node?

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I have accessed the children of this Users node. But every time I try to update the score and analysis of one child, others will be affected causing the other child to have the same value.

[image: This is the firebase console]

This is the code i am using to access the children under Users for the score

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = rootRef.child("Users").orderByChild("username");

    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {        
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) ds.getValue();
                    map.put("score", total);
                    ds.getRef().updateChildren(map);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    };
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

This is the code i am using to access the children under Users for the analysis

```
 DatabaseReference dr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query q = dr.child("Users").orderByChild("username");

        ValueEventListener vel = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) ds.getValue();
                    map.put("analysis", sev);
                    ds.getRef().updateChildren(map);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        };
        q.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(vel);
    }
```

I have to update Analysis and Score without affecting other children

Comment: Where are you getting this value `usersName` from (on the line `if(usersName == usersName){`) and what is its purpose?

Comment: that is wrong. i was just trying things. that should not be there.

Answer (score 1):

Use `equalTo(theusername)` to specify which users you are trying to get access-update:

So the query will be:

```
Query query = rootRef.child("Users").orderByChild("username").equalTo(theusername).child("score");
```

// or `analysis` instead of `score`

And in your listener:

```
ValueEventListener vel = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                   // update the value here ...
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        };
        q.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(vel);
```

Comment: theusername? @Mohsen

Comment: `But every time I try to update the score and analysis of one child` I said that because of this line of yours. Yes, if you're trying to change a specific user's value, you can specify a username or UID of the user and then you'll be able to change the value for the specific user.

Comment: it should not be specific. I cant use equalTo("Rona") or equalTo("Zillah")

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve? For only one user or ? It will actually effect all items in there since the fields are like the same and you're doing the same for all users. It's better to specify which user field you're trying to update.

Comment: i have to be in the field of Rona or Zillah first. before it will change the score and the analysis.

Comment: Because you're doing the update for all children and you didn't specify a field or user item, it will definitely update all childrens. You have two options, **1**. specify which `username` you are trying to change **2.** Specify by getting UID of the user to change specific user item.

Comment: Cool. You can add another child called `UID` or, using the name of the user, or, using `UID`  which is available also by Firebase `getUID` of the current user.